# How to set focus on a control with Appium in Windows (WPF, Desktop)?

Tags: appium-desktop

I'm automating a WPF desktop app in Windows.
We're currently switching from CodedUI to Appium, as the former is deprecated.

I'm trying to click a control that is currently not visible, as it requires the user to scroll down.
It's worth noting that, for some reason, when inspecting the control (via Inspect.exe tool), its `Displayed` property == `True` and `isOffscreen` == `False`.

With **CodedUI** I can simply invoke `EnsureClickable()` and it will automatically scroll to the control, if necessary.

In **Appium** there seems to be no straightforward way to do it. I can't find any way to set focus on a control.
I tried invoking `new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(element)` but that only produced

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Currently only pen and touch pointer input source types are supported
```

Any ideas?